# Find a point along a circles edge

Tags: analytic-geometry

[image: Image/Description of what I am trying to do]

As I have tried to demonstrate in the above image, I am trying to find Cartesian coordinates along a circles edge.

I have a *heading* angle in radians from the center of the circle and I have the magnitude of a vector point outwards along that angle that I can set to any length. Call this simply *R* as radius of the circle. 
I also have the center point of the circle as *J*.

Using this information, how could I find the Cartesian coordinates for any given angle, any given J, and any given R so that I could draw a line from point (x, y) *eg = (0, 0)* to the coordinates.

Thanks heaps for the help.

Comment: In the special case $J=0$, do you know how to do it?

Comment: @Arthur at J = 0, the Cartesian point should; I assume, be (-x, -y) or (-x, y) I still want to calculate this as no, I do not know how to do this. I'm effectively just actually trying to find the point on the circle. The line is there just to clearly demonstrate what I am trying to calculate

Comment: Let's say, also for simplicity, that $(x_1,y_1)=(0,0)$. What are the coordinates of a point on a circle centered at the origin? You have an angle, you have a radius. Draw it, see if you can spot something.

Comment: @Arthur to clarify, the lines I am drawing above are more to show that I want to find the points along a circle. I just need those points. Not so much the line. I want to use these points to set a velocity vector of a given object in a program I am writing. This is maybe a clearer idea of what I am trying to find: https://imgur.com/a/uV1OSAM

Answer (score 1):

This turned out easier than I was making it out to be, and I'll probably get down voted alot for posting a somewhat stupid question, but for any others who have this question. I found the answer:

(x, y) that you want to find along a circles edge is equal to =

x = circleCenterX + radius * cos(angleInRadians)

y = circleCenterY + radius * sin(angleInRadians)